# OpenShift - Application packaging

Tags: node.js, nginx, redis, openshift, packaging

I have a NodeJS API that sits behind a Nginx reverse proxy and connects to a Redis instance. To deploy this on to OpenShift cluster, I need the following:

- Nginx image e.g. [registry.access.redhat.com/rhscl/nginx-114-rhel7](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-nginx114/)
- Redis image e.g. [registry.redhat.io/rhel8/redis-5](https://access.redhat.com/containers/?tab=images#/registry.access.redhat.com/rhel8/redis-5)
- NodeJS code hosted on GitHub

I am not sure if [OpenShift Operators](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/applications/operators/olm-what-operators-are.html) and [Helm Charts](https://helm.sh/) are the right choice - they sound like an overkill (or, are they?). Then, there are YAML based installations e.g. [Strimzi on OpenShift](https://strimzi.io/quickstarts/okd/).

Given a OpenShift cluster with `oc` installed, perhaps, there is yet another way; where, all of the following commands are wrapped in a shell script.

```sh
git clone https://github.com/me/nodejsapi
oc new-project awesome
# Trigger S2I for NodeJS
cd nodejsapi
oc new-app .
# New applications with nginx image
oc import ...
# New applications with redis image
oc import ...
# New config map set-up through [OpenShift APIs][6]
curl ...
```

Can you please advise the *suitable* approach to install the NodeJS application and others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask me creating an Operator for this is overkill. Using a Helm chart is more of the correct abstraction. The easiest solution on OpenShift is to to use a Template.

Comment: Thanks for the endorsement! ;-) The helm chart would still have to be hosted on `helm.sh` is it? If you won't mind, can you please help me with an example of OpenShift Template? This example (https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.2/openshift_images/using-templates.html#templates-writing_using-templates) isn't very easy to understand. :-D

Comment: I think you can use a local helmchart as well. No need to host them on helm.sh if you do not want to.

As for a template for your example:

 nginx: https://github.com/omarmohsen/openshift-nginx-template/blob/master/nginx-template-rhel7.yaml

nodejs: https://github.com/sclorg/nodejs-ex/blob/master/openshift/templates/nodejs.json

redis: https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/examples/db-templates/redis-persistent-template.json

Try to combine all these into a single template, if you really need there to be only a single template.

Comment: I would advice you to read that page you linked to from start to finish to learn more about templates.

A Template will replace all ${VALUE} placeholders with values from the parameters that you send in. Note that a parameter can be generated for you or it can have a default value.

Answer (score 0):

For me if your app need many pods with different technologies, the right choice is helm chart. But, if you don’t want use it, an alternative is to use a deployment file in yaml or json.
Here an example for SQL Server 2019
https://github.com/chauuy/sqlserver.git

Note: a template file is also available to add SQL Server ephemeral (without persistent storage) as new component like MySQL etc...